# PrestoDB Query to concat data from rows and columns into one string

Tags: presto

I Have a table like and want to insert an additional column by joining data from multiple rows an d columns.
[image: I Have a table like:]

and wanted result as:
[image: and wanted result as:]

Tried :

```
concat_ws(':', nrarf, chDl, Indicator, carrier, cellTech, Coreset, mer1NR)
```

but i am not getting the desired result, I am getting the output as given below, please help.[image]

Comment: You need to do a string Aggregation after CONCATing them. Use STRING_AGG(ConcatedData,',')

Comment: How do you get the values for the `nraf`, `chDl`, `cellTech`, `Coreset`, ... columns?

Comment: concat_ws is not available in presto what are you using to query?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only concats columns. Below code, I think is what you want.

```
Declare @FinalString nvarchar(max) = ''

Select @FinalString += Concat(col1, ':', col2, ':', col2, ....) + ','
FROM table_name
```